# Rxjs from() operator doesn't send data

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have a simple app on Angular/rxjs/Ngrx which requests list of default films from the api.

**component.ts**

```js
export class MoviesComponent implements OnInit {
  private movies$: Observable<{}> = 
  this.store.select(fromRoot.getMoviesState);
  private films = [];

  constructor(public store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new MoviesApi.RequestMovies());
    this.movies$.subscribe(film => this.films.push(film));
    console.log(this.films)
  }
```

**effects.ts**

```js
  @Effect()
  requestMovies$: Observable<MoviesApi.MoviesApiAction> = this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType(MoviesApi.REQUEST_MOVIES),
      switchMap(actions => this.MoviesApiServ.getDefaultMoviesList()
        .pipe(
          mergeMap(movies => of(new MoviesApi.RecieveMovies(movies))),
          catchError(err => {
            console.log('err', err);
            return of(new MoviesApi.RequestFailed(err));
          })
        )
      )
    );
```

**service.ts**

```js
export class MoviesApiService {
  private moviesList = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  public getDefaultMoviesList(): Observable<{}> {
    DEFAULT_MOVIES.map(movie => this.getMovieByTitle(movie).subscribe(item => this.moviesList.push(item)));
    return from(this.moviesList);
  }

  public getMovieByTitle(movieTitle: string): Observable<{}> {
    return this.http.get<{}>(this.buildRequestUrl(movieTitle))
      .pipe(retry(3), 
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

}
```

DEFAULT_MOVIES is just array with titles.

So my **getDefaultMoviesList** method is not sending data. But if I replace this.moviesList to hardcoced array of values it works as expected.
What I'm doing wrong?

UPD
I wanted to loop over the default list of films, then call for each film **getMovieByTitle** and collect them in array and send as Observable. Is there any better solution?

Comment: Did you try returning `of(this.moviesList);`
**Interesting fact is `Observable.of([])` will be an empty array when you subscribe to it. Where as when you subscribe to `Observable.from([])` you wont get any value.**

Comment: @nircraft, I wanted to loop over the default list of films, then call for each film **getMovieByTitle** and collect them in array and send as Observable. Is there any better solution? and yes I tried of() and nothing happend

Comment: Yes you can do something like this:
`const apiCalls = [];
DEFAULT_MOVIES.forEach(movie=> {
  apiCalls.push(this.getMovieByTitle(movie));
});
Observable.forkJoin(apiCalls).subscribe(responses => {...});`

Comment: @nircraft, it's weird but I tried **of()** once again and now it works as expected. Thank you so much! Now I can accept your answer

Comment: glad it helped.

Comment: @nircraft could you please add your answer so I can mark it as accepted? thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try creating the observable using `of` operator.

Ex: `of(this.moviesList);`

One intersting fact to note is that `Observable.of([])` will be an empty array when you subscribe to it. Where as when you subscribe to `Observable.from([])` you wont get any value.

`Observable.of`, is a static method on `Observable`. It creates an Observable for you, that emits value(s) that you specify as argument(s) immediately one after the other, and then emits a complete notification.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The only thing that will be emitted is an empty array every time. `of` doesn't help one bit. You can just replace the whole service with `return of([])`

Answer (score 0):

1) You should probably move this line to the service contructor, otherwise you will push a second array of default movies every time you `getDefaultMoviesList`:

```
DEFAULT_MOVIES.map(movie => this.getMovieByTitle(movie).subscribe(item => this.moviesList.push(item)));
```

2) Actually you should probably `merge` the output of each `http.get`:

```
  public getDefaultMoviesList(): Observable<{}> {
    return merge(DEFAULT_MOVIES.map(movie => this.http.get<{}>(this.buildRequestUrl(movieTitle))
      .pipe(retry(3), 
        catchError(this.handleError)
      )))
  }
```

3) You should actually only do that once and store it in `BehaviorSubject` not to make new HTTP request on each `getDefaultMoviesList`

```
private movies$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>();

public getMovies$() {
  return this.movies$.mergeMap(movies => {
    if (movies) return of(movies);
    return merge(DEFAULT_MOVIES.map(movie => this.http.get<{}>(this.buildRequestUrl(movieTitle))
      .pipe(retry(3), 
        catchError(this.handleError)
      ))) 
  })
}
```

4) Your implementation shouldn't work at all since:

```
public getDefaultMoviesList(): Observable<{}> {
  DEFAULT_MOVIES.map(movie => this.getMovieByTitle(movie).subscribe(item => 
        this.moviesList.push(item))); // This line will happen after http get completes
  return from(this.moviesList); // This line will happen BEFORE the line above
}
```

So you will always return an Observable of empty array.

5) You shouldn't use `map` if you don't want to map your array to another one. You should use `forEach` instead.

`map` is used like this:

`const mappedArray = toMapArray.map(element => someFunction(element));`